# WinForms -> toolbox for fast display of data

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, user-interface, datagridview

I'm new to C# and WinForms, and i'm developing an application, which would allow me to read data from serial port and display it on some display tool (listview,...).

Now, i got serial communication and other functionalities working, but i'm having a problem with displaying the data. I need to be able to display incoming data really fast (every 1ms). To display data (for now), i'm using dataGridView, but the problem is that dataGridView is not fast enough.

So my question is: Is there some way to display data that fast? I know the human eye can't really see data in this interval, but still... It would be prefered to display data in dataGridView-like display, since it's really easy to organize data.

Best regards, 
Nejc

Comment: Did you try using a double-buffered DGV subclass?

Comment: What do you mean by DGV subclass? I enabled DoubleBuffer property to true for my form. Is that the same as DGV subclass?

Comment: Does a user really need to see that much data that fast?  Only update the display in reasonable chunks.

Comment: No. Each control needs to turn on its own graphics for doublebuffering. Exception: `PictureBox`, which has it on by default. But only the `Form` actually has the property exposed. Others like `Panel` or  `DGV` need to be subclassed to set it, e.g: `public class DBDataGridView : DataGridView {public DBDataGridView () {DoubleBuffered = true;}}` Add e.g. after the forms class (ie before the last curly) or add to the project. Compile. Drag from the toolbox..

Comment: With 60/50Hz display the screen refreshes every 16/20ms respectively. What's the point of  updating your controls every 1ms, when user will see changes once every 16 to 20 updates  ?

Comment: @TaW thans for your help, this improved my performance significantly. It still needs a little optimisation but it's a lot better. I found one way to optimize datagridview yesterday, and i'll give it  a try later. 
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to succeed displaying data every 1 ms. What you should do is buffer the incoming data on one thread, then every N incoming data, call on a method to display the data (i.e. you will be adding N rows at a time). Note you will need to use Invoke() as you will be calling on the GUI from a different thread (the thread that receives the data, not the thread that created the GUI).